# Как убрать свойство из общего потока свойств битрикс

Tags: битрикс

помогите убрать несколько свойств из общего потока катрочки товара. В характеристики выводятся свойства rating, vote_count, vote_sum которые нужно исключить. Код вывода всех свойств такой:

```
<?foreach($params as $prop):?>
<?if($prop["VALUE"] != ''):?>
<tr><td><span><?=$prop["NAME"]?></span></td>
<td><b><?=$prop["VALUE"]?></b> <span style="color:#000" ><?=$prop['DESCRIPTION']?></span></td></tr>
<?endif?>
<?endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$excludedProps = ['rating', 'vote_count', 'vote_sum'];

<?

    foreach($params as $prop):

         if (in_array($prop['CODE'], $excludedProps)) {
             continue;
         }

?>
<?if($prop["VALUE"] != ''):?>
<tr><td><span><?=$prop["NAME"]?></span></td>
<td><b><?=$prop["VALUE"]?></b> <span style="color:#000" ><?=$prop['DESCRIPTION']?></span></td></tr>
<?endif?>
<?endforeach?>
```

Вариант 1: можете сделать проверку по коду свойства перед выводом информации

Вариант 2: в настройках компонента убрать эти свойства из отображения и тогда не придется трогать код, если конечно свойства не тянутся из массива ['PROPERTIES']